# After using react-router the onClick event is not firing the function in first time and works fine after that

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, onclick

This was working fine with React when I was not using it inside BrowserRouter and Route, after using react-router the onClick event is not firing the function in first time and works fine after that

This is the function that I need to be triggered on onClick

```
function clickHandler() {
    
const signUp = document.getElementById("signUp");
const signIn = document.getElementById("signIn");
const container = document.getElementById("container");

signUp.addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.classList.add("right-panel-active");
});

signIn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.classList.remove("right-panel-active");
});

    }
```

This is the code for my form that I am rendering

```
      <div className="container" id="container">
        <div className="form-container sign-up-container">
          <form action="#">
        </div>
        <div className="form-container sign-in-container">
            <button>Sign In</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        **<div onClick={clickHandler} className="overlay-container">**
          <div className="overlay">
            <div className="overlay-panel overlay-left">
              <button className="changeForm" id="signIn">
                Sign In
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="overlay-panel overlay-right">
              <button className="changeForm" id="signUp">
                Sign Up
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

---React Router code---

```
  function App() {
      return (
            <Router>
             <Fragment className = "App">
              <Route exact path = "/form" component = {AuthForm} />
             </Fragment>
            </Router>
             );
                }
```

Comment: In React you should use the provided synthetic events and not create your own event listeners (unless actually required). button will provide an `onClick` property which will allow you to provide a function `(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void` to run on click of the element.

Answer (score 1):

On click events should be registered via the provided synthetic events.

```
// React function component
const ComponentA = () => {
    // Create on click function using useCallback (function component ONLY)
    // This ensures the function is not recreated on each rerender.
    const onButtonClick = React.useCallback((event) => {
        alert('Button Clicked')
    }, []);

    // Render view (attaching on click function to the button)
    return (
        <button
            onClick={onButtonClick}
        >
            Test
        </button>
    )
};
```